# How to get physicians where they have more than one reporting specialty in a system

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

Reportingspeciality

```
ID  Speciality     HospitalName
1    Neurology      Sun
2    Emergency      Jefferson
5    Pulmonary      Mary
5    Anesthesiology Mayo
```

PhysicianJMGreportiongspeciality

ID   JMGReportingSpeciality
11     Physician Assistant
17       Anesthesiology
21       Anesthesiology

PhysicianName

```
FirstName  LastName      ID
Sam         ABC           5
Joseph      DEF           2
Sam         ABC           5
Jackson     DEF           1
```

Output wanted

```
FirstName   LastName    ID   Hospital  Specialty
Sam           ABC       5     Mary      Pulmonary
Sam           ABC       5     Mayo      Anesthesiology
```

also group by ID and Hospital
Anesthesiology is the bad data in the table which I have to obtain in the result.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the obvious query?

```
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  PhysicianName.ID,
  HospitalName
FROM
  PhysicianName
INNER JOIN
  Reportingspecialty
ON
  PhysicianName.ID = Reportingspecialty.ID
GROUP BY
  PhysicianName.ID, HospitalName
```

And why are there two exactly identical rows in the name table?